# PHP $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] shows IPv6

Tags: php, ipv6

I am facing an issue with $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] in PHP 
It is giving a IPv6 like value even though the server is using IPv4.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure that your server is running on IPv4?

Comment: This is because your web server is binding to [::], not 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The server is then accepting connections on an IPv6 socket. Some operating systems can do both IPv4 and IPv6 on an IPv6 socket. When that happens the IPv6 address will look like `::ffff:192.0.2.123` or `::ffff:c000:027b` which is the same address but written in hexadecimal.

If you see IPv6 addresses like `2a00:8640:1::224:36ff:feef:1d89` then your webserver really *is* reachable over IPv6 :-)

Anyway, to convert everything back to a canonical form you can use something like:

```
// Known prefix
$v4mapped_prefix_hex = '00000000000000000000ffff';

$v4mapped_prefix_bin = hex2bin($v4mapped_prefix_hex); 

// Parse
$addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$addr_bin = inet_pton($addr);
if( $addr_bin === FALSE ) {
  // Unparsable? How did they connect?!?
  die('Invalid IP address');
}

// Check prefix
if( substr($addr_bin, 0, strlen($v4mapped_prefix_bin)) == $v4mapped_prefix_bin) {
  // Strip prefix
  $addr_bin = substr($addr_bin, strlen($v4mapped_prefix_bin));
}

// Convert back to printable address in canonical form
$addr = inet_ntop($addr_bin);
```

Using this code, when you input one of the following:

```
::ffff:192.000.002.123
::ffff:192.0.2.123
0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:c000:027b
::ffff:c000:027b
::ffff:c000:27b
192.000.002.123
192.0.2.123
```

you always get the canonical IPv4 address `192.0.2.123` as output.

And of course IPv6 addresses get returned as canonical IPv6 addresses: `2a00:8640:0001:0000:0224:36ff:feef:1d89` becomes `2a00:8640:1::224:36ff:feef:1d89` etc.

Comment: Thanks. I will do something to filter the IP.

Comment: I tried adding all your examples to my test script, and I never execute the striping of the prefix.  Are there too many 0's in your sample code for all your examples?

Comment: No, all the examples are valid. Can you show your test script?

Comment: inet_pton("192.000.002.123") gives a Warning and returns false on PHP 5.3.6-10.

Comment: qbolec: That is a bug on your platform then... Please go to https://bugs.php.net/ and file a bug report so it can get fixed.

Comment: @qbolec inet_pton("192.000.002.123") generates warning