# php get user IP trouble

Tags: php, apache, ip, localhost

I'm using XAMPP platform( php, apache, mysql ). I connecting to apache via localhost. I want to know user ip using this php code:

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

And I get on my page in my browser.

```
::1
```

Comment: It actually is the IPv6 address used for `localhost`. So what is the question?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435582/php-serverremote-addr-shows-ipv6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::1` is the localhost in IPv6. Looks ok

Answer (score 0):

As i commented it seems ipv6 , actually showing   loopback addr ,

any way if you want ipv4 change it in server configuration , i think surplus tuts where available

test yourself with this singler

```
echo "Server Configured to use  ". (strstr($_SERVER("REMOTE_ADDR"), ".")) ? "IPv4" : "IPv6" ;
```

or if just want to test its ipv(4/6)

```
 if (((strstr($_SERVER("REMOTE_ADDR"), ".")) ? 4 : 6 )==4)
  {
   //ipv4
  }

  else

 {
  //ipv6
 }
```