# Store both IPv4 and IPv6 address in a single column

Tags: mysql, ipv6, ipv4

I want to be able to store both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses in my table.  What is the most efficient way to store the IP address of a user regardless of whether it is an IPv4 or IPv6 address?

This will be used in a production environment, so future proof'd suggestions are preferred.

Comment: An IPv4 Address is 32-bits long. An IPv6 Address is 128-bits long. For Storage Efficiency IPv6 Addresses can be stored in a `BINARY(16)` column however this is inefficient for IPv4 Addresses which would be better in an `INT UNSIGNED` column.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444771/how-to-store-a-128-bit-number-in-a-single-column-in-mysql

Comment: @AeroX if i use `BINARY(16)` , will i be able to store the ipaddress as is e.g 192.168.1.2 or i need to perform some conversion

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend to store every address in IPv6 format. There is an official mapping for that: the [IPv4-mapped IPv6 address](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.5.2). It works like this:

Take for example IPv4 address `192.0.2.44`
The IPv4-mapped IPv6 address would be `::ffff:192.0.2.44`
Which can also be written as `::ffff:c000:022c` (`192` decimal is `c0` hexadecimal, etc)

You can use the `inet_pton()` function to parse such addresses, and on my local system the `inet_ntop()` function also outputs them in the most readable format (`::ffff:192.0.2.44`). That way you only have one format to deal with in your application.

Also see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435582/php-serverremote-addr-shows-ipv6/12436099#12436099).

Comment: Do every ipv4 address have a ipv6 equivalent?.Also will i be able to convert those ipv6 addresses back to ipv4.Can you suggest the best datatype and size needed to store ipv6 for mysql

Comment: Use a BINARY(16) for the IPv6 address, and if you follow the 'related answer' link you will see how to convert back.

Answer (score 1):

Why does it have to be a single column? A few suggestions...

Have 2 columns, one for IPv4, one for IPv6.

Store the IP address in a single column and have another column that basically holds a boolean whether the address is IPv4 or not...

Comment: It would be a waste of resources since ipaddress isn't that much important.I mean that it would be retrieve from the database only in rare cases.Only one version is needed